# How do I determine the page location immediately?

Tags: angularjs

I have a main menu on my website for every page except the login page.  In my html, I have:

```
<div ng-if="$root.location !== '/login'">
    <mainmenu></mainmenu>
</div>
```

This works in general, except the main menu flashes when I load the login page.  I suspect this is because the menu is shown, then the variable $root.location becomes /login, then the main menu disappears.

How do I do this so the main menu doesn't flash?

Comment: Try using ng-cloak directive on your div (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak). That could solve your problem with menu flashing

Comment: Bohuslav - Thanks for this. One thing I didn't mention, my mainmenu does a database hit.  I don't think ng-cloak would prevent that from happening.  From the documentation, it seems it just hides it.  I'm looking for a way to prevent the menu from being loaded (preventing the flash and the db hit)